# self modifying python script

Tags: python, self-modifying

I want to create python script which can modify code in that script itself using [Python Language Services](https://docs.python.org/3/library/language.html) or using any other way.
e.g. A script which keep track of its count of successfull execution

```
import re
COUNT = 0

def updateCount():
    # code to update second line e.g. COUNT = 0
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('This script has run {} times'.format(COUNT))
    updateCount()
```

On successful execution of this script code should get changed to

```
import re
COUNT = 1

def updateCount():
    # code to update second line e.g. COUNT = 0
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('This script has run {} times'.format(COUNT))
    updateCount()
```

Simple approach came to my mind was to open `__file__` in write mode and do requried modification using reguler expessions etc. But that did not work I got exception `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable`. Even if this approach would be working then it would be very risky because it can spoil my whole script. so I am looking for solution using Python Language Services.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can use the language services to achieve self-modification, as in following example:

```
>>> def foo(): print("original foo")
>>> foo()
original foo
>>> rewrite_txt="def foo(): print('I am new foo')"
>>> newcode=compile(rewrite_text,"",'exec')
>>> eval(newcode)
>>> foo()
I am new foo
```

So, by new dynamically generated code you can replace stuff contained in the original source file, without modifying the file itself.

Answer (score 9):

A python script is nothing more than a text file. So, you are able to open it as an external file and read & write on that. (Using `__file__` variable you can get the exact name of your script):

```
def updateCount():
    fin = open(__file__, 'r')
    code = fin.read()
    fin.close()

    second_line = code.split('\n')[1]
    second_line_parts = second_line.split(' ')
    second_line_parts[2] = str(int(second_line_parts[2])+1)

    second_line = ' '.join(second_line_parts)
    lines = code.split('\n')
    lines[1] = second_line
    code = '\n'.join(lines)

    fout = open(__file__, 'w')
    fout.write(code)
    fout.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

@kyriakosSt's answer works but hard-codes that the assignment to `COUNT` must be on the second line, which can be prone to unexpected behaviors over time when the line number changes due to the source being modified for something else.

For a more robust solution, you can use `lib2to3` to parse and update the source code instead, by subclassing `lib2to3.refactor.RefactoringTool` to refactor the code using a fixer that is a subclass of `lib2to3.fixer_base.BaseFix` with a pattern that looks for an expression statement with the pattern `'COUNT' '=' any`, and a `transform` method that updates the last child node by incrementing its integer value:

```
from lib2to3 import fixer_base, refactor

COUNT = 0 # this should be incremented every time the script runs

class IncrementCount(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    PATTERN = "expr_stmt< 'COUNT' '=' any >"

    def transform(self, node, results):
        node.children[-1].value = str(int(node.children[-1].value) + 1)
        return node

class Refactor(refactor.RefactoringTool):
    def __init__(self, fixers):
        self._fixers = [cls(None, None) for cls in fixers]
        super().__init__(None)

    def get_fixers(self):
        return self._fixers, []

with open(__file__, 'r+') as file:
    source = str(Refactor([IncrementCount]).refactor_string(file.read(), ''))
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(source)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/MushyStrangeClosedsource

Answer (score 0):

This will edit the module level variables defined before `_local_config`.  Later, process an update to the dictionary, then replace the `line` when iterating over the source file with the new `_local_config` values:

```
count = 0
a = 0
b = 1
c = 1

_local_config = dict(
    filter(
        lambda elem: (elem[0][:2] != "__") and (str(elem[1])[:1] != "<"),
        globals().items(),
    ),
)

# do some stuff
count += 1
c = a + b
a = b
b = c

# update with new values
_local_config = dict(
    filter(
        lambda elem: elem[0] in _local_config.keys(),
        globals().items(),
    )
)

# read self
with open(__file__, "r") as f:
    new_file = ""

    for line in f.read().split("\n"):
        for k, v in _local_config.items():

            search = f"{k} = "

            if search == line[: len(k) + 3]:
                line = search + str(v)
                _local_config.pop(k)
                break

        new_file += line + "\n"

# write self
with open(__file__, "w") as f:
    f.write(new_file[:-1])
```